# We're dropping our beta tag. What will Google do about it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo

Until now, our ASP.NET MVC site was accessible at http://beta.fleex.tv. Now that we dropped our beta label, it is located at http://fleex.tv.

We set up an http redirect from beta.fleex.tv to fleex.tv through our domain name registrar, 1&1. That redirect is pretty brutal: it doesn't look at the page consulted, just the domain, and will for instance redirect http://beta.fleex.tv/page?arg=0 straight to http://fleex.tv.

I have 2 questions:

- Is there a simple way to redirect http://beta.fleex.tv/page?arg=0 to http://fleex.tv/page?arg=0? Is this a good idea, or should we instead delete beta.fleex.tv altogether?
- What should we do with Google?

  - If we keep the 'beta' pages, what will happen to them in Google's index? With the current redirects in place they all point to http://fleex.tv. My guess is that Google will start detecting duplicate content (or even redirected content) and delete everything from the index, but I'd love to understand how things will go in more details
  - If we submit a new sitemap with all the fleex.tv nodes, will Google penalize us in any way or will it simply start indexing those pages from scratch, untouched by the beta.fleex.tv debacle?

Generally speaking I'd love to know what you guys think about what the best strategy might be here. This seems like a fairly common problem. I feel there's no way to avoid losing all the indexing that Google has done, in that case though I'd just like to know how this whole operation will affect our 'reputation' with Google...

Please shoot questions if this is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to SEO this is a disaster. You *need* to do page-level 301 redirects.

Having a different sub-domain was a mistake from the beginning because now it causes trouble and links pointing to you are now inaccurate.

Redirecting is not particularly hard to do: in `Application_BeginRequest` look at the `Request.Host` and `Request.RawUrl` properties and redirect if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to give the same advice as usr, but to reiterate - this will absolutely murder your rankings and traffic from organic if you don't fix it, especially long tail ones.

You've got about a three-four week grace period to get page level stuff implemented before you start to lose value from the old URLs.

I would also add that because you're using 302s instead of 301s (very common in ASP.NET environments), Google will take much longer to view the redirects as permanent, repeatedly checking back to see if the pages have moved - and therefore not passing value from the subdomain to the main domain - and from personal experience will in the end pass less link value overall.

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=2613318